# Equivalent of "lock and xadd" assembly instructions on PowerPC

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I am looking for the equivalanet of the following x86 assembly instructions for AIX PowerPC.

lock 
xadd

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `lwarx` and `stwcx.` to emulate.

Answer (score 6):

Atomics on PowerPC are implemented using the `lwarx` (load word and reserve indexed) and `stwcx.` (store word conditional indexed) instructions.

The former, `lwarx`, performs a load and acquires a "reservation" on the cacheline used for the load. This reservation is lost if another processor acquires that cacheline - typically by another processor doing a store to that same memory address, or even another address in the same cacheline (more on this later) .

The `stwcx.` instruction performs a store, but *only if* the reservation (that we acquired with an earlier `lwarx`) is still valid. The condition register is updated to indicate whether the store was successful.

Using these, we can implement the `lock xadd` - by acquiring a reservation on the location you want to update. Using the following definition of `lock xadd`:

```
Temporary = Source + Destination;
Source = Destination;
Destination = Temporary;
```

Using:

- r1 as pointer to a 'Destination' word in memory
- r2 to contain the 'Source': the value to add and exchange
- r3 as an output, to contain the original value of 'Destination'
- r4 as a temporary register

Something like this might work:

```
retry:
    # load the word addressed in r1 into r3, and create
    # a reservation for that address
    lwarx   r3, r0, r1

    # r4 = r3 + r2
    add     r4, r3, r2

    # if we still have the reservation, store r4 into the address
    # in r1...
    stwcx.  r4, r0, r1

    # ... otherwise, try again
    bne-    retry
```

However, this is quite a simplistic case - there are other things to consider when implementing atomic for any architecture. For example:

- The memory address needs to be correctly aligned
- We're assume word-sized accesses here. Use the `lbarx`, `lharx` and `ldarx` instructions, and their `st*cx` pairs, for different access sizes.
- Also, you'll need to ensure that you have your memory accesses ordered correctly if you're making any other assertions about data consistency.
- The reservation is for the entire cacheline - so you may need to ensure that other accesses to the same cacheline are managed correctly.

For this (and other) reasons, it's generally better to use system-provided atomic libraries instead of coding your own. For example, `gcc` provides `__sync_add_and_fetch`, which may be suitable for your case.

If you're after more information, check out Book II of the Power ISA, in Section 4.4.2.